# Python RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

I am practising a really easy python code. I have tried to find the solution of it, but couldn't find it.

```
def del_contacts():
for name, number in d1.items():
    if (del_name == name):
        del d1.name and print ("Contact deleted!")
else:
    print ("Contact does not exist")

z = input ("Do you wish to delete any of the number you added? ")
if z == 'yes':
    del_name = input ("Type the name of the contact you wish to delete")
    del_contacts()
else:
    print ("ok")
```

but this gives me error `in <module> del_contacts()` 
followed with 
`in del_contacts for name, numbers in d1.items(): RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Have been facing such problem a lot. Can anyone please tell me WHY this error is happening? Any fix and what should I do in future to avoid such errors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are modifying the dictionary while iterating over it.
Just create a copy of the dict when getting the items

```
def del_contacts():
    for name, number in d1.copy().items():
        if (del_name == name):
            del d1.name and print ("Contact deleted!")
        else:
            print ("Contact does not exist")
```